# PowerBI - visuals: Project build errors

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi

I've been trying to setup the PowerBI visualizations github project in visual studios 2013, but seem to get a ridiculous amount of build errors (200+).Some of the errors thrown were:

*"Incorrect reference: file "D:\PowerBI-visuals\src\Clients\VisualsCommon\obj\VisualsCommon.d.ts" does not exist"*

*"Error 102 Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.*"

*"Error 6   ';' expected."*

*"Error 102 The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."*

**What I did to setup:**

After making sure I had git and node installed, I executed the following three commands successfully:

1. git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals.git
2. cd PowerBI-visuals
3. npm install

The npm install command seemed to work just fine. I then open the solution in VS 2013 and tried to build the project but was presented with errors.

Any idea what I may of done incorrectly in the setup procedure?

Answer (score 1):

- The solution should be opened in VS 2015 or in VisualStudioCode (free
  versions).

  - Visuals builds using Gulp.
  - Visual Studio 2013 does not support Gulp tasks.
  - Visual Studio 2015 by default use gulpfile.js to
    build Visuals.
  - Also you can build the Visuals using this command:
    gulp build. (from the root folder of the Visuals)

P.S. - In VS2015, Don't forget to do this (as mentioned in instruction):Right click on the project root folder then select 'Property Pages'. In the window opened select 'Build' and then in 'Before running startup page' select 'No Build'

Comment: I think the main reason of error above is not setting 'No Build'' option - I have Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and it works